# Handling updates on nested screens using Context and React Navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Let's say I am building a shopping list app. I have the ability to create different shopping lists. I have three screens:

```
-- Shopping Lists: displays all the lists
---- List Details: displays all the items from a list
------ List Item Details: displays all the info about an item
```

To store the state and avoid prop drilling I use Context. My state could look like:

```js
shoppingLists = [
{
  title: 'Groceries',
  items: [{
    name: 'Apples',
    quantity: 3
    ... (other info)
  },
  items: [{
    name: 'Oranges',
    quantity: 6,
    ...
  }]
},
{
  title: 'Office Supplies',
  items: [{
    name: 'Paper',
    quantity: 2
    ... (other info)
  },
  items: [{
    name: 'Pens',
    quantity: 25,
    ...
  }]
}]
```

When I tap on a Shopping List on the Shopping Lists screen I do

```js
navigation.navigate('ListDetails', {params: listItem})
```

In the List Details screen I have de ability to change the quantity of an item or delete them. If I do any of this actions I have to make an API call to my server to update the value on the database. Here are my questions:

1. Currently I store the values in a local variable in my screen for example:

```js
const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.route.params.title)
const [items, setItems] = useState(prop.route.params.items)
```

And if I make a change in the quantity I use setState to update my local array and then make an API call to update the context. This results problematic when adding more nested screens.
For example if I would give the user the ability to change the item quantity in the List Item Details screen, when the user goes back to the List Details screen, the values would not be updated.

My question is, which is the correct way to grab the state of the context and update it locally?
For example should I do something like:

```js
navigation.navigate('ListDetails', {params: { listName: 'Groceries' })
```

And then in my List Details screen grab the correct list from the array like:

```
const {lists} = useContext(ShoppingLists)
const list = lists.filter(l => l.title === props.route.params.title)
```

What is the correct way?

2. The other question I have is a more general question. I want to use optimistic responses: when the user updates the quantity of an item in the list I update it locally and send the request to the server. If there's an error rollback the change. Which would be the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I would advise against updating context data in such a way. You could create a `setList()` method in the context instead, or `updateList()` to aggregate new data to the existing data.
2. This is related to the previous one. You could wrap the logic of POSTing to the server in a try-catch block and throw an error when it's not successful. Then you can set the new value only when it's successful. Another option would be to return the promise, so you could handle errors from outside, like `setList().then(response => {}).catch(error => {})` though I don't think this looks that good.

Answer (score 0):

Think you're over complicating it and also in your list you're not showing an `id` for each item. You should build your database with all the items and their unique `id` then call upon that when needed. The `id` should never change and that's easier to pass around and reference.

For example you can build an object in context with just the `id` and `quantity` and use `useReducer` for this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer